# Python: subprocess.Popen returns OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

In my script I have the below line:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["qstat", "-xml", "-u", "*", "-r", "-s", "r"],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It works fine when I run it, but when it is set up as a cronjob I am getting back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File 
File "/seq/software/current/bin/createOpsDashboard.py", line 171, 
in get_pod_occupied_slots
proc = subprocess.Popen(["qstat", "-xml", "-u", "*", "-r", "-s", "r"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/software/free/Linux/redhat_5_x86_64/pkgs/python_2.7.1-sqlite3-rtrees/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__ errread, errwrite)
File "/software/free/Linux/redhat_5_x86_64/pkgs/python_2.7.1-sqlite3-rtrees/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is causing this? The cronjob is calling a shell script which load Python-2.7 and then calls the real script.

Comment: Could file permissions be the problem? (chmod 755 or something?)

Comment: unrelated: are you sure you want to pass `*` literally instead of `glob.glob('*')`?

Answer (score 4):

Use full path for "qstat", e.g. "/usr/local/bin/qstat". PATH environment variable for cronjob is usually restricted to default path (e.g. /bin:/usr/bin).